# Is it possible to cast an sObject to another object that is dynamic?

Tags: apex, list, sobject, typecast, casting

I'm having a problem with my code because I need to get a list of records of a dynamic type, and that is working alright, but then I need to use some of the fields and can't reach them, giving me the error

> Variable does not exist

Here is a sample of the code:

```
    String queryString = 'select Id, '+ camposMainObj.get(0) +', '+  
    camposMainObj.get(1)+', '+ camposMainObj.get(2) +', test__c from ' 
    +sObjName+ ' where Id = \''+recordId+'\'';

    List<sObject> obj = database.query(queryString);

    system.debug('sObjName ::::::::: '+obj);

    string listType = 'List<'+sObjName+'>';

    List<sObject> castRecords = (List<sObject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();

    castRecords.addAll(obj);

    system.debug(castRecords);


    ChartObject__c co = new ChartObject__c();
    co.Pai__c = castRecords[0].Id;
    co.PaiName__c = castRecords[0].Name;
    co.PaiEmail__c = castRecords[0].Email__c;
    co.PaiPhone__c = castRecords[0].Phone__c;
```

The variable `sObjName` contains the correct object type (in this case `Pai__c`).

Only the Id is recognized. The result query looks like this:

```
    (Pai__c:{Id=a070O00001uWD58QAG, Name=pai1, Phone__c=910987654, Email__c=pai1@mail.com, test__c=asdf}
```

So I can get every field from the query, but can only get the Id on the new object and it matches the queried one. The Name, Phone__c, Email__c, etc give me that error. I tried many solutions but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex requires types to be known at compile time to directly reference fields.

But there are are `get` methods in the [SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) for this case where the field names can be used in string form:

```
List<sObject> objects = database.query(queryString);
for (sObject o : objects) {
    String name = (String) o.get(camposMainObj.get(0));
    String email = (String) o.get(camposMainObj.get(1));
    String phone = (String) o.get(camposMainObj.get(2));
    ...
}
```

but it is up to you to cast to the correct type as the return value of `get` is `Object`.